# what is the best way to customize threading depending on device Capabilities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jmonkeyengine

i'm developing an android 3d game

the game can run better on a high devices capability

but still i can boost up the game by reducing textures or by customize the frame rate of the game or also increase the time for custom thread to sleep etc.

but i need to do that according to the device

i mean the best practice to do so

i'v thinking in do something like this

```
int count = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
if(count < 4){
   //// load low textures and decrease frame rate and so on
}else{
   //// load high textures and increase frame rate and so on
}
```

but i know that it isn't a reliable or a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I think that solely using the amount of processors won't be a reliable method. So much is governed by the capabilities of the GPU.
I see two options;

1. Let the user decide (like most games do)

Preconfigure a number of profiles and let the user try them using a menu. Some people will prefer slower performance in favor of better graphics, and vice versa. Who are we, as developers, to decide which is preferable?

2. Run a performance test and decide based on that

Load something (a small scene), run it for a short while with unbound framerate. Measure the performance (`tpf` for example) and decide the capabilities based on that.